# $ is not defined error in production environment Rails 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ujs

jQuery and ujs work fine in the development environment, but are not working in production environment.

This is what my code looks like:

**application.html.erb**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  </head>
  <body>
      <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/sortable
//= require js-routes
//= require semantic-ui
//= require swiper
//= require cocoon
//= require tree_table
//= require jquery_throttle_debounce
//= require trix
//= require_tree .

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

Any page that uses the application layout has **ujs** not working and is getting **$ is not defined** error for **jquery** codes in production environment only.

Note: I recently removed turbolinks from the application.

Comment: Have you checked the generated code? Does it contain jQuery?

Comment: Your shouldn't need to assign `window.jQuery` or `window.$` in the first place - the gem version makes it global anyways.

Comment: Also since you're not using `// require_self` before `//= require_tree .` the code after it in  `application.js` will actually be after all the subdirectories are slurped